# Moose && utf8 (package|method) names

Tags: perl, utf-8, moose

Having this:

```
use utf8;
package ÁngryBird;   #note the Á in the package name
```

`perl -c` result is **`syntax OK`**.

```
use utf8;
package ÁngryMoose;
use Moose;
```

`perl -c` says,

```
ÁngryMoose is not a module name at 
/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4/darwin-multi-2level/Class/MOP/Package.pm
 line 209.
```

So, what's wrong in the code?

Comment: Related: http://p3rl.org/perl58delta#Unicode-in-package%2fclass-and-subroutine-names-does-not-work

Comment: @daxim , please, can you be a bit more precise? What part of perl-delta you mean as related?

Comment: @cajwine, daxim has an internal link there, which points out that Unicode package names simply don't work according to the perl 5.8 delta. I'm not sure if it got cleared up since then.

Comment: Ok, just found it. So, now the question is, why in the 1st example (without Moose) was the syntax OK. Why such difference?

Comment: I think the most relevant quote from the documentation is: "While some limited functionality towards this does exist as of Perl 5.8.0, that is more accidental than designed".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Moose` uses [this regexp](http://metacpan.org/source/DOY/Package-Stash-0.33/lib/Package/Stash/PP.pm#L37) from `Package::Stash::PP` for checking package name:

```
elsif ($package !~ /\A[0-9A-Z_a-z]+(?:::[0-9A-Z_a-z]+)*\z/) {
    confess "$package is not a module name";
}
```

or [this regexp](http://metacpan.org/source/DOY/Package-Stash-XS-0.25/XS.xs#L807) from `Package::Stash::XS`:

```
const char *vmre = "\\A[0-9A-Z_a-z]+(?:::[0-9A-Z_a-z]+)*\\z";
```

But you [may create your own package stash inplementation](http://metacpan.org/module/Package::Stash#DESCRIPTION) in namespace `Package::Stash`, and use it by setting environment variable `PACKAGE_STASH_IMPLEMENTATION` or variable `$Package::Stash::IMPLEMENTATION` before loading `Package::Stash`. For example, if your implementation have name `Package::Stash::My` then set variable to `My`.

Comment: OK, thanx. Soo this is an intentional Moose "feature". :( Maybe in the perl v23.7...

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Package::Stash. Please file a bug in rt.cpan.org.

Comment: The bug already filed 8 months ago as [#72057: over-strict rules for module names](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=72057). No response. Maybe should we force it?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like it may be a `Class::MOP` bug. Have you tried asking there, or reporting a bug?